# Why is "log_set_prohibit_ipc" set to true in systemd-journald?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-journald

I have just started to learn `journald` and in its `main()` function (in `journald.c`) I encountered a function call `log_set_prohibit_ipc(true);`

Can anyone tell me why is it set to true by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `systemd` source, you can see the declaration in `src/basic/log.h`:

```
/* If turned on, then we'll never use IPC-based logging, 
 * i.e. never log to syslog or the journal. We'll only 
 * log to stderr, the console or kmsg */
void log_set_prohibit_ipc(bool b);
```

So it seems like this function will prevent `journald` from writing to the journal.  In fact, if we look at all uses of this:

```
stew ~/src/systemd-246.1/src $ grep -rw log_set_prohibit_ipc 
shutdown/shutdown.c:        log_set_prohibit_ipc(true);
shared/generator.c:        log_set_prohibit_ipc(true);
journal/journald.c:        log_set_prohibit_ipc(true);
core/manager.c:        log_set_prohibit_ipc(!manager_journal_is_running(m));
core/main.c:                log_set_prohibit_ipc(true);
basic/log.h:void log_set_prohibit_ipc(bool b);
basic/log.c:void log_set_prohibit_ipc(bool b) {
```

We see that `log_set_prohibit_ipc( ... )` is set to `true` everywhere except for `core/manager.c` (which is the main systemd manager).  Even then, the manager is logging only if no other manager is running.

A bit of speculation here, but I'm guessing that means the primary manager will log things on behalf of the other systemd components, avoiding duplicate or internal logs.  It could also be that this is an implementation of a singleton design pattern, possibly to simplify the multiple-writer concurrency problem.

Comment: Journald not writing to journal itself by default is strange, isn't it? I have another query, What do we mean by "indexing" of logs for faster lookup? , Journlad does this
I have seen this word in docs but no clear explanation, is it related to addition of timestamp, process_name, log_priority (info,debug...) to the log messages ?

Comment: "Indexing" in general means an index is being created.  It doesn't affect the content directly, but creates auxiliary file where it keeps a record of some indexed parameter (such as unit) and points to data related to that parameter.  If you use `journalctl -u someunit`, it will be quicker to retrieve the entries indexed by unit instead of parsing all entries and selecting the ones you want.  But that's all internal to the journal's implementation.  I don't know which parameters are indexed and I doubt the index is a stable external format that you can reliably parse in a script.